# How can i get records from my table there is more than 2 days old

Tags: mysql

Why wont my interval day work in mysql statement.

I want those who is more than 2 days old. This is how i tried.

```
SELECT t.*, ct.*,cd.*, max(t.transactiontime) as maxtime
FROM exp_channel_titles as ct
LEFT JOIN transactions as t on (ct.entry_id = t.restaurant_id)
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_data as cd on (ct.entry_id = cd.entry_id)
WHERE t.cardid > 0 
and maxtime < ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY )
and t.restaurant_id > 0
and ct.status= 'open'
Group by ct.entry_id
order by maxtime desc
```

This is my current output

```
TransactionID          Title           TransactionTime
23132                  Locaton         2013-05-17 10:02:04
23131                  Novuel          2013-05-16 16:26:45
23128                  Mama Rosa       2013-05-15 14:42:44
23126                  Rohan           2013-05-14 12:46:56
```

This is my desired output

```
TransactionID          Title           Date
23128                  Mama Rosa       2013-05-15 14:42:44
23126                  Rohan           2013-05-14 12:46:56
```

But i am getting this error

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'maxtime' in 'where clause'

SELECT t.*, ct.*,cd.*, max(t.transactiontime) as maxtime FROM exp_channel_titles as ct LEFT JOIN transactions as t on (ct.entry_id = t.restaurant_id) LEFT JOIN exp_channel_data as cd on (ct.entry_id = cd.entry_id) WHERE t.cardid > 0 and maxtime < ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY ) and t.restaurant_id > 0 and ct.status= 'open' Group by ct.entry_id order by maxtime desc

Filename: libraries/Functions.php(656) : eval()'d code

Line Number: 46
```

Comment: `SELECT ... WHERE Date < ADDTIME(now(), '-48:00:00');`

Comment: I just updated my question with the error i am getting

Comment: You cannot use alias in where or order by clause... you have to use actual function that you have used `max(t.transactiontime)`....

Comment: Can you show me an example of it ?

Comment: this `maxtime < ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY )` should be moved from `WHERE` clause to `HAVING` clause that you need to add it after `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: Thanks Meherzad and Stephan. It worked! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
maxtime < DATE_FORMAT( NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY ,'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
```

`CURDATE()` returns `DATE` type and you need `DATETIME` type so you should use `NOW()`

Comment: instead of putting the condition on `WHERE` clause (this was why the error occurred ) put it in `HAVING` clause like `HAVING max(t.transactiontime) < DATE_FORMAT( NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY ,'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')`

Answer (score 1):

in your query you use CURDATE  but as I understand your date column is datetime data type so..

NOW() = 2008-11-11 12:45:34

CURDATE() = 008-11-11

CURTIME() = 12:45:34

this is what the mysql functions return. use the correct function here

```
maxtime < ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY )
```

change CURDATE() to NOW()  but this my not be the solution for you. you need to find out.

Comment: in this approach the records that have the time (H:i:s) greater the the time from NOW() will be ignored ex : NOW() -  INTERVAL 2 DAY = 2013-04-15 13:17:00 and a record with the date 2013-04-15 13:18:00 will be ignored , get my point ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use alias name in where clause,used max(t.transactiontime)< ( now() - INTERVAL 2 DAY )